# How to force an image to be full screen that must be in a Bootstrap 4 container?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am using a Wordpress page template where I have the content of the parent template and then below that I display the content of the child templates, which includes the featured image. The content must display in the `container` class but the featured images must be full screen. The problem is that I cannot seem to separate the code to make this possible. I am not even sure if it is possible. Maybe it is via JQuery? The image I want to be full screen is in the `foreach` loop near the bottom of the code below.

Here is a rough example of my code:

```
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>" id="content">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 content-area" id="primary">

                <main class="site-main" id="main" role="main">

                    <?php

                    $parent_id = get_the_ID();

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'post_parent' => $parent_id,
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                    );

                    $rooms = get_posts($args);

                    ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'page' ); ?>

                        <?php
                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                            comments_template();
                        endif;
                        ?>


                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


                    <?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ) : ?>

                        <!-- THIS BELOW IS THE PROBLEM -->

                        <div class="acc-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php  echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($room->ID);?>')"></div>

                        <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#accommodation-navbar" data-offset="0">
                          <h1 id="<?php echo $room->ID; ?>"><?php echo $room->post_title; ?></h1>
                          <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $room->post_content ); ?>
                          <p><?php echo get_post_meta($room->ID, "fireplace", true); ?></p>
                        </div>


                    <?php endforeach; ?>


                </main><!-- #main -->

            </div><!-- #primary -->

        </div><!-- .row end -->

    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your image is in the DOM it will take position from its parent element.

To enable fullscreen on your image you could use this css trick:

```
.acc-bg {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it works perfectly, I feel so silly. Hopefully this will help for future coders who have the same issue. Thanks man :)